# Should I use count(*) or count(a, b, c.., z) when counting the number of rows in a query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Should I use `select count(*) from XXX` or `select count(a, b, c.., z) from XXX`?

when counting the number of rows in a query,  which one is faster (if there is any difference in them) ?

Comment: When you are looking at SQL it helps understanding if you translate * as "the rows".

Comment: Also note that `select count(*)` is the same as `select count(1)` or `select count('a constant')`: all those will count the number of rows. (As opposed to the number of rows for which column [col you're counting] is null.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually they are different. If for example `a` has NULL values you will get only number of records where `a` is not null. So you shoud use slect count (*) for counting the number of rows in a query

Answer (score 4):

Well lcount(a,b,c,d) will produce a syntax error on most databases,
you would need count(a),count(b),count(c),count(d).

If you want a count of the number of rows than use count(*).

If you want to count how many rows which have a not null value for a particular column then count(col).

Answer (score 2):

Because with `COUNT(*)` oracle counts the number of rows, and with `COUNT(field)` it counts the number of values in `field` that `NOT NULL`. Which is obviously slower.